# print nested lists in columns in Lisp

Tags: layout, formatting, output, lisp, common-lisp

I have a doubt on how to print several matrix-like nested lists in a row, row after row, vertically aligned so they appear in columns one under the other.

I tried several ways but none of it works and  I've used several text formats but it's not coming out as expected.  any suggestions?

I updated the doubt and I hope that now you can understand.

```
(defun tabA()
  '((X 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
    (0 0 0 X 0 0 0) 
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
    (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)))

(defun tabB()
  '((0 0 0 0 X 0 0) 
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
    (0 T 0 0 0 0 0) 
    (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)))

(defun tabC()
  '((0 0 0 T 0 0 0) 
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
    (0 0 X 0 0 X 0) 
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
    (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)))

(defun states ()
  (list (tabA) (tabB) (tabC)))

(defun test-print ()
  (format T "~%--- Result ---")
  (mapcar #'(lambda(x) (print-state x)) (states)))

(defun print-state (x)
  (format T "~%")
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (format T "~@T~@T~@T~@T~@T ~A ~%" x)) x)
  (format NIL ""))

  ;;test print
  (test-print)
```

you can test and see the result in [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/6HrSmN) like this example

```
--- Result ---
  (X 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 

  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 

  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 X 0 0 X 0) 
  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

and I want to print these lists in two or three columns, like this example

```
--- Result ---
(X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0) 
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0) 
(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0) 
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)

(0 0 0 T 0 0 0) 
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
(0 0 X 0 0 X 0) 
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how the desired output relates to the input. The top left box is `first`, but I can't find the rest.

Comment: FYI, `#'(lambda(x) (print-state x))` can be written as just `#'print-state`

Comment: Common Lisp does not have an output feature like that in its default library. You need to program it.

Comment: I agree with Barmar: these are not the same lists: in the second, desired, example there is no list with an `X` in the second column.  The question makes no sense as it stands.

Comment: Transform your data to columnize it (the inner-most list element will have e.g. 2 colums or one row), then call another mapcar function to walk the columns for each row. Walking the columns will mean not printing a ~% at the end of each, then append the ~%, go on to the next row.

Comment: @tfb, you right, I just put this example not the real code, because the list I need to print in column is the result of dfs and bfs

Comment: @AlbusMPiroglu, thanks for suggestion, I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If input is regular as in the example data, this can be done simply enough by looping over the row indices of the tables and looping over the tables themselves to print the rows in sequence:

```
(defun print-tables (tables)
  (let ((rows (length (first tables))))
    (loop for n below rows do
         (terpri)
         (dolist (table tables)
           (format t "~A  " (elt table n))))))
```

The `print-tables` function takes a list of tables as its argument. Here it is assumed that the tables are all the same shape with regular column widths. The number of `rows` is calculated for the first table, and the `loop` counts row indices starting with 0, printing a newline with `(terpri)` before each sequence of table rows is printed. The `dolist` iterates over the `tables` and for each table the `n`th row is printed. The same approach could be used for more irregular data, with some additional formatting code.

```
SCRATCH> (print-tables (list (tabA) (tabB) (tabC)))

(X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0)  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 X 0 0 X 0)  
(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
NIL
```

The above code just prints the tables in sequence in a single row of tables, but for larger numbers of tables it would be nice to group the tables sensibly. A `group-tables` function can be written and used in a `print-groups` function making use of the above `print-tables` function.

```
(defun group-tables (grouping tables)
  (labels ((iter (tables group)
             (cond ((null tables)
                    (list group))
                   ((= (length group) grouping)
                    (cons group
                          (iter tables '())))
                   (t
                    (iter (rest tables)
                          (append group (list (first tables))))))))
    (iter tables '())))
```

Here `group-tables` takes a list of tables and an integer argument specifying the maximum grouping desired per output line. The local `iter` function builds up a list of groups, but each group is constructed in an accumulator as progress is made; note  that `append` is used here to keep the tables in the same order as input.

```
(defun print-groups (grouping tables)
  (dolist (group (group-tables grouping tables))
    (print-tables group)
    (terpri)))
```

Here `print-groups` just uses `group-tables` to collect the tables into groups, then uses `dolist` to pick out each individual group for processing by the `print-tables` function.

Sample REPL interactions:

```
SCRATCH> (print-groups 3 (list (tabA) (tabB) (tabC)))

(X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0)  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 X 0 0 X 0)  
(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
NIL
SCRATCH> (print-groups 2 (list (tabA) (tabB) (tabC)))

(X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0)  
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  

(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 X 0 0 X 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
NIL
SCRATCH> (print-groups 3 (list (tabA) (tabB) (tabC) (tabA) (tabB) (tabC)))

(X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0)  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 X 0 0 X 0)  
(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  

(X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0)  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 X 0 0 X 0)  
(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
NIL
SCRATCH> (print-groups 4 (list (tabA) (tabB) (tabC) (tabA) (tabB) (tabC)))

(X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 X 0 0)  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (X 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 T 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 X 0 0 X 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  

(0 0 0 0 X 0 0)  (0 0 0 T 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 T 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 X 0 0 X 0)  
(0 0 0 X 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  (0 0 0 0 0 0 0)  
NIL
```